# Jmeter Post request is returnin a sample answer for Get

Tags: jmeter

I am using reqres sample API for practising purposes.
I am sending a post request and expecting a sample response that can be seen on the screenshot.
I have applied http header manager with content type - application/json and in the request itself I activated Redirect Automatically box. What can be the issue? I have encountered the same problem with another testing API so I do not think it's reqres which is the problem.

[image]
However, I get an response as if I am sending a get request
[image: The reqres request]
[image]

In the request body is clearly states that I am using a post request.

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to say what's wrong without seeing your full test plan and request/response data in the [View Results Tree](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#View_Results_Tree) listener

As per [documentation](https://reqres.in/) it seems you're just using an incorrect password, the request body should be:

```
{
    "email": "eve.holt@reqres.in",
    "password": "pistol"
}
```

[image]

So assuming you have:

1. [HTTP Request](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request) sampler with the method [POST](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Methods/POST) and the above body
2. [HTTP Header Manager](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/http-header-manager) with [Content-Type](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Type) header of `application/json`

you should get the same response as it's stated in the documentation

Demo:

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much, the problem was that I did not give the protocol "Https" and Jmeter was treating the request as if it's a GET request. 
With the protocol set it gives a correct failed message "{"error":"Note: Only defined users succeed registration"}". Before that I was getting a sample response for a get request

Answer (score 1):

The problem was with the protocol: If it's left empty, JMeter treats a post request as if it's a get request:

[image]

[image]

If we give the protocol, JMeter treats post as a post request. The GIF video from Dmitri helped me to figure it out:

[image]
[image]